# Does setting currentTime always trigger canplay?

Tags: html5-video

I can't find an exact answer online. The closest I get is a [description](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video) of the canplay event.

> The user agent can resume playback of the media data, but estimates that if playback were to be started now, the media resource could not be rendered at the current playback rate up to its end without having to stop for further buffering of content.

Here is my code

```
// fyi at this point i just loaded the video from an <input>. the currentTime is 0.
var posterFrame = 3;
var longEnough = vid.duration >= posterFrame;

vid.oncanplay = function () { getThumb.apply(self); }
vid.currentTime = longEnough ? posterFrame : 0;
```

It works just fine for me but I am concerned that sometimes setting currentTime won't trigger oncanplay and the whole thing will just stop.

Answer (score 1):

While writing my own html5 video player, I came across this same question. Further searching lead me to this bug report:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=773885

which suggests the behavior as a dupe to bug report 664842. While 664842 is specific to the related 'canplaythrough', there is related discussion by Mozilla devs:

> The spec says: canplaythrough fires when "readyState is newly equal to HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA.".
>
> Elsewhere it says "When the ready state of a media element whose networkState is not NETWORK_EMPTY changes, the user agent must follow the steps given below: [...] If the new ready state is HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA [...] the user agent must finally queue a task to fire a simple event named canplaythrough."

There is a followup request to make canplay & canplaythrough one time events here:

https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=12982

which says the behavior won't be changed.

> Firefox interprets the spec as allowing canplay/canplaythrough to be fired multiple times as readyState changes allow.  This interpretation is useful because canplaythrough is fired optimistically based on estimated transfer completion time.  This estimate may become invalid if, for example, network conditions or the bitrate of the media changes.  It is useful to signal this change in state by moving to and from HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA (and firing the related events) as conditions change.
>
> Seeking to a new location in the media may result in a previous canplaythrough estimate becoming invalid if the seek location is in an unbuffered segment of the media that requires a new network request to transfer or significant decoding work.  It then becomes more consistent (and therefore easier to code against) if these events are also fired when seeking to a range that is already buffered.

Although that discussion is from 2011, considering that the behavior seems to still be implemented, I think it's safe to say that yes, it should alway trigger it, so long as you don't pass it anything odd like null media.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include the essential parts of the linked  pages into your answer.

Comment: I can only include two links but I'll copy & paste the relevant parts.

Comment: Yep, that's what is needed: the content of those pages relevant to the question should be in the answer, so it is still accessible if a link goes dead, and also anyone having the same issue won't have to search the whole page.

Comment: Ok added in. The issue is that in their responses, they include citations to the spec. Since I can only post 2 links, I can't include their citations and thus can't quote them verbatim. I believe I've included enough content to satisfy your request, however.